# TFS 2010: How to handle external "branched-in" dependencies on working branches

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

Is there an established "best practice" for handling external dependencies in TFS working branches? What I mean is, we have a project in TFS that contains common third-party libraries (in this case I'm specifically dealing with log4net), which we branch into our other projects as needed. Now we're making a significant change that I'm doing on a separate working branch, which requires a newer version of the component. It looks basically like this:

```
$/ThirdParty
  /bin
    /log4net

$/Product
  /Main
    /thirdparty
      /lognet      <-- $/ThirdParty/bin/log4net
  /Working1        <-- $/Product/Main
    /thirdparty
      /log4net     <-- $/Product/Main/lognet <-- $/ThirdParty/bin/log4net
```

Part of the work requires rebuilding log4net against the .NET 4 client profile and bringing in the new version. Normally, when we upgrade a third party component, it's checked into `$/Thirdparty` in the appropriate folder, then the individual projects are free to merge the latest binary, or not, as they see fit.

As far as I have can determine, in order to get the latest changeset from `$/ThirdParty/bin/log4net` I need to merge that into `$/Product/Main`, **check the merge into TFS**, then merge that branch into `$/Product/Working1`. That's exactly what I want to avoid, because I don't want to disrupt the main branch.

So, I guess two questions:

1. Is there a way to get this merge to work without having to check anything into the main branch?
2. Is there a better overall strategy for handling these kind of dependencies while still keeping them in TFS? (I know TFS isn't "meant" for binaries, but we like it because of the easy multiple-version and history tracking we get out of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to 1:
Yes. You can do a baseless merge from ThirdParty to Working1. Here's the MSDN page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668976.aspx

As for 2:
If your Main project can use 2+ different versions of your 3rd party binary, then I recommend storing the separate versions of the 3rd party binary in the $/ThirdParty area and not having a direct link between files in the 3rd party area and the Main area.

Comment: Eventually, the version bump in the working branch will also get made in the main brach, just not immediately. If I do a baseless merge directly into Working1, will that changeset want to get merged back into Main later on? And the reason we keep the binaries in TFS like this is to keep all the projects on the same version of certain libs (especially strong-named ones like log4net). Since our core libraries reference it, everything else has to use the same version or else we have to do run-time assembly binding redirects. (And this time the SNK changes so even that won't work.)

Comment: Yes. After doing a baseless merge to Working1, you can merge that from Working1 into Main or from ThirdParty into main (or do both and TFS should catch that the binary is identical). We force all apps in our release to use the same version of a 3rd party dll, and I haven't dealt with strong-named 3rd party dlls yet, so I'll keep your way in mind, as my next 3rd party dll will be strong-named.

Answer (score 0):

Why not eliminate the ThirdParty project altogether? Just keep all versions of the 3rd party libs on a file share and check the appropriate one into each project's tree as appropriate.